# Passing data from Activity to Activity using Otto is not working

Tags: java, android, otto

It's the first time that I'm using this library, but I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVqBmGK3VuA) video tutorial to send data through Fragments, but in my case, it's just Activities.. So this how I did

**Activity that I'm sending data :**

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    String passing_data = new Gson().toJson(user);
    BusStation.getBus().post(new MessageData(passing_data));
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity,UserAdsView.class);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

**BusStation Class :**

```
public class BusStation {
    private static Bus bus = new Bus();

    public static Bus getBus() {
        return bus;
    }
}
```

**MessageData Class :**

```
public class MessageData {
    private String msgData;

    public MessageData(String msgData) {
        this.msgData = msgData;
    }

    public String getMsgData() {
        return msgData;
    }
}
```

**And finally at the UserAdsView Activity :**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    BusStation.getBus().register(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    BusStation.getBus().unregister(this);
}

@Subscribe
public void recievedData(MessageData messageData){
    target = messageData.getMsgData();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), target, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

As was mentioned on video, this method  `recievedData` should be fired!

Answer (score 4):

When you send notification in first activity at that time, `UserAdsView Activity` is **not registered** hence there are **no** listeners for events.

At this line

```
 BusStation.getBus().post(new MessageData(passing_data));
```

you are sending notification but there is nothing registered to receive this notification. i.e. `UserAdsView Activity` has not started yet.

> If you need to pass data to activity at launch time, simply send it via 
>   [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Comment: So what I need to do? Override a onStart and BusStation.getBus().register(this); ?

Comment: No. see my updated answer. You can just send data to activity in the `Intent`

Comment: You can use `Sticky Event` in that case.

Comment: I'm going to search about it.

Comment: You can also make your **MessageData object parcelable**. See nipun.birla's answer.

Comment: I am not sure if `Otto Bus` supports this feature but Green Robot's `Event Bus` has this sticky event thing. https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Answer (score 1):

**add in file Gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
}
```

Create class OttoBus

```
public class OttoBus {
    private static Bus sBus;
    public static Bus getBus() {
        if (sBus == null)
            sBus = new Bus();
        return sBus;
    }
}
```

**Create Events Class when pass data in android**

```
public class Events {

    public static class FragmentActivityMessage {

        private String message;

        public FragmentActivityMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }
    }

    public static class ActivityFragmentMessage {

        private String message;

        public ActivityFragmentMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }
    }

}
```

function pass data

```
 public void sendMessageToFragment(View view) {
        EditText etMessage = findViewById(R.id.activityData);
        OttoBus.getBus().post(String.valueOf(etMessage.getText()));
    }
```

function event getdata

```
@Subscribe
    public void getMessage(Events.ActivityFragmentMessage message) {
        TextView messageView = findViewById(R.id.message);
        messageView.setText(message.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that but it should be  OttoBus.getBus().post(new Events.ActivityFragmentMessage(String.valueOf(etMessage.getText())));

Comment: Thanks you , OttoBus.getBus().post(String.valueOf(etMessage.getText())); you can change OttoBus.getBus().post(new Events.ActivityFragmentMessage(String.valueOf(etMessage.getText())));

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your MessageData object parcelable.

Then in your `onClick()` :

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    String passing_data = new Gson().toJson(user);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putParcelable("key",new MessageData(passing_data));
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity,UserAdsView.class);
    intent.putExtras(extras)
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then in `onCreate()` of your UserAdsView Activity :

```
MessageData data = (MessageData)getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("key");
```

Comment: `getExtras()` does not exist.

Comment: It's `getIntent().getExtras()`

Comment: here at `new MessageData(passing_data));` it says that I need to cast, and I did, but the app just return to a previously Activity.

Comment: Did you make MessageData class parcelable?